# Flask data storage in session with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, session-cookies

I have a lot of data (about 30 columns) from different HTML pages to store:

1. a string (can be retrieved by id) randomly generated with Javascript
2. a form with data from user input
3. a list of values generated with Javascript

With Flask framework, most of the sessions are done on the Python file (app.py) itself. Is it possible to store data on session with Javascript or Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). There are two kinds:

[Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> Maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's
>   available for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser
>   is open, including page reloads and restores)

[Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> Does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

Comment: If I use Session Storage, would I be able to retrieve that session data with Python?

Comment: Think of web storage as client-side storage, and Flask sessions as server-side storage. They'll need to communicate the same way your client and server communicate. So, you can use things like headers, cookies, request params/body, etc. to send the information you need between the two.

Comment: Is there a most efficient way to send all of web storage data into the server-side storage?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a way to save session data in Javascript, try:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('item name', 'item value')
```

And retrieve with:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('item name')
```